# JSTL call parameterized void method

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, sling

I am currently searching for a possibility to use a void method mit parameters in JSTL.

The Java class is a Sling Model and worked into the JSTL via adaptTo.
Is there any way to use other methods than get or set in JSTL?

Rough Code (I don't think it really is important, what the function does?)

```
 public void someMethod(final Parameter parameter1, final Parameter parameter2) {
does.some.stuff();
}
```

This may be a very stupid and easy question but I just find Bean stuff.
Please help me out?

Thank You!

Comment: So you haven't tried `${bean.someMethod(param1, param2)}` as documented? Or are you working on a legacy beast where this EL 2.2 feature wasn't supported?

Comment: I have the problem, that the method seems to start more than just the one time necessary.

Comment: Then you have multiple calls to the very same method.